# Convert UTC format to dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss format in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of dates in the format
`2019-11-04 00:33:15 UTC` that I need to format into `04/11/19 hh:mm:ss`. 
I've tried this:

```
df1["date"]= pd.to_datetime(df1["date"])
```

But it's returned `NaT` in all entries. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!!

Comment: Does it return NaT for the given date (`2019-11-04 00:33:15 UTC`), if so I cannot reproduce.

Comment: It returns NaT for all values in the 'date' column

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: datetime64[ns, UTC]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this to easily convert the format. I hope this helps you.

```
date = [["2019-11-04 00:33:15"],["2019-11-14 00:43:15"],["2019-11-25 06:33:15"],["2019-11-27 09:33:15"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(date, columns = ['Date']) 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

[image: Working Example]

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to reproduce the exact thing to the best of my knowledge.

You have something with the format:

> 2019-11-04 00:33:15 UTC

```
df['old_format'] = ['2019-11-04 00:33:15 UTC', '2019-11-04 00:33:15 UTC']
```

I am now converting it to datetime type with the exact type:

```
df['old_format'] = pd.to_datetime(df['old_format'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', errors='coerce')
```

And now converting it to your required format:

```
df['new_format'] = df['old_format'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Sample output:

```
                 old_format           new_format
0 2019-11-04 00:33:15+00:00  04/11/2019 00:33:15
1 2019-11-04 00:33:15+00:00  04/11/2019 00:33:15
```

Given your comments, my old_format is also of the same type. Here it is to cross check:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
old_format    2 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
new_format    2 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Still returning NaT. Not sure why. I'm new to this :/

Comment: Could you please try with errors='coerce' inside the to_datetime?

Comment: Yes. That worked. It returned this 04/11/2019 hh:mm:ss - with literally the time values as hh:mm:ss. How can I get the actual time, minute, second values?

Comment: I have updated the answer and the output according to your requirments. In short, to get the actual values just replace hh:mm:ss with %H:%M:%S.

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)